# Xamarin.android Where to use google play licence key in plugin.inappbilling

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am new to android and I want to implement in-app purchase within my app.

As i am working with xamarin, I have used this plugin
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin

I have read documents available from google and I have read docs section of this plugin too.

I want to ask about the licence key google play console gives us. Where to put that key ? In docs section, it is mentioned that it is used to verify purchase. And they have given seperate interface for it.

This key is not used at all while purchasing the product ? Is it optional ?

Please help me to resolve my confusion.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is an optional feature for paid applications that wish to verify that the current user did in fact pay for the application on Google Play as stated in this [document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/). This is also available for free application to use licensing service to initiate the download of an APK expansion file. In which case, the request that your application sends to the licensing service is not to check whether the user paid for the app, but to request the URL of the expansion files.

> Adding license verification with the LVL involves these tasks:
>
> - [Adding the licensing permission](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing#manifest-permission) your application's manifest.
> - [Implementing a Policy](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing#impl-Policy) — you can choose one of the full
>     implementations provided in the LVL or create your own.
> - [Implementing an Obfuscator](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing#impl-Obfuscator), if your Policy will cache any license response data.
> - [Adding code to check the license](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing#impl-lc) in your application's main Activity.
> - [Implementing a DeviceLimiter](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing#impl-DeviceLimiter) (optional and not recommended for most
>     applications).

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot for answer! I got it now. :)